# Positive probability that two autoregressive sample paths have the same sign

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

Suppose I have two autoregressive processes of order one, that is,
\begin{align}
X_{t+1} &= \beta X_t + \varepsilon_{t+1}, \\
Y_{t+1} &= \beta Y_t + \varepsilon_{t+1},
\end{align}
where $0<\beta<1$ and $X_0,Y_0>0$ given. It can be shown that the differences between these two paths converges to zero at exponential rate, since
$$
|X_t-Y_t| = \beta|X_{t-1}-Y_{t-1}| = \beta^t|X_0-Y_0|.
$$

> **Question:** Suppose that $(\varepsilon_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a stationary and ergodic sequence. What other assumptions do I need to guarantee that there is a positive probability that the two sample paths always have the same sign, that is, 
>   $$
> P(X_t>0 \Leftrightarrow Y_t>0, \,\forall t\in\mathbb{N})>0.
> $$

**Thoughts:** In the easier case that $(\varepsilon_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ is iid I can show that the probability is positive if $\varepsilon_t$ is absolutely continuous with full support and bounded probability mass function. This follows essentially by
$$
P(X_t>0 \Leftrightarrow Y_t>0, \,\forall t\in\mathbb{N}) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_t>0 \Leftrightarrow Y_t>0, \,\forall t\le n).
$$
Moreover if $M$ is the bound on the pmf of $\varepsilon$, then 
\begin{align}
&P(X_t>0 \Leftrightarrow Y_t>0, \,\forall t\le n)  \\
\ge (1-\beta^n|X_0-Y_0|M)&P(X_t>0 \Leftrightarrow Y_t>0, \,\forall t\le n-1).
\end{align}
This leads to a converging (nonzero) product, thus showing the result.

Does anyone know how to deal with these kind of questions when we have to take the conditional distributions $\varepsilon_t\mid\varepsilon_{t-1},\ldots,\varepsilon_1$ into account?

Thank you in advance!